# [Azure][Bot Service] Is there an API to remove conversations from directline 3.0 chache?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I'm interested if there is a way to remove conversations and it's data from the regional directline 3.0 chache (like europe.directline.botframework.com). I am aware that all conversation data is only stored for [24 hours in the regional directline chache](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/issues/119) and know how to delete the state data in the bot's logic.

The reason I am asking is that the conversation and it's messages contain sensitive data and the directline cache is considered a risk, if we are not able to remove the messages or the whole conversation programmatically via the directline api, for example if the conversation between the user and bot is over.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is not a capability to flush the messages for a conversation or
> user in Direct Line sooner than the 24 hour limit. This is something
> one could do with Update and Delete activities that we have in our
> backlog but do not have any delivery date for. I will add this as a
> scenario for that feature.
> See: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/219

An alternative to get around the 24h issue is to use the [Direct Line App Service Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), because it is always just sending the messages to either the client or the bot directly and not storing them in any cache.